# How to translate SQL query with multiple grouping in EF equivalent

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I have a database (PostgreSQL) where there is a main table `student`, additional information `amount` and 3 dictionaries. I make a query with grouping by three fields of dictionary IDs, output the number of objects and the amount from an additional table with a condition. And how to translate it to EF Core 6?

```
create table region (id serial primary key, name varchar);
create table district (id serial primary key, name varchar);
create table department (id serial primary key, name varchar);

create table student (
    id serial primary key,
    name varchar,
    region_id bigint references region,        
    district_id bigint references district,
    department_id bigint references department
);

create table amount (
    id serial primary key,
    student_id bigint references student on delete cascade,
    value numeric,
    year int
);
```

My SQL query is working well:

```
select
    t.region_id,
    region."name" region_name,
    t.district_id,
    district."name" district_name,
    t.department_id,
    department."name" department_name,
    t.cnt,
    t.value
from (
    select
        region_id,
        district_id,
        department_id,
        count(distinct s.id) cnt,
        sum(a.value) "value"
    from student s 
    join amount a on s.id = a.student_id 
    where a.year = 2020
    group by region_id, district_id, department_id
) t
join region on t.region_id = region.id
join district on t.district_id = district.id 
join department on t.department_id = department.id
```

How do I get names from dictionaries when translating a query to EF?

```
[Table("student")]
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("name")]
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    [Column("region_id")]
    public int? RegionId { get; set; }

    [Column("district_id")]
    public int? DistrictId { get; set; }

    [Column("department_id")]
    public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(RegionId))]
    public virtual Region? Region { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(DistrictId))]
    public virtual District? District { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(DepartmentId))]
    public virtual Department? Department { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Amount>? Amounts { get; set; }
}
```

EF query:

```
var result = await db.Student
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.RegionId, x.DistrictId, x.DepartmentId })
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        x.Key.RegionId,
        x.Key.DistrictId,            
        x.Key.DepartmentId,
        Cnt = x.Count(),
        Value = x.Sum(c => c.Amounts.Where(v => v.Year == 2020).Sum(v => v.Value))
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

At the moment I have such a solution, but will such a request be optimal in the end? In addition, you need to add a null check here.

```
RegionName = x.First().Region.Name,
DistrictName = x.First().District.Name,
DepartmentName = x.First().Department.Name,
```

Comment: Why you do not use `join` as in SQL? LiNQ query in query syntax will be almost the same.

Comment: LINQ is so much slower than the Database query. Highly recommend to write a store procedure and call the store procedure using EF in your scenario. Databases are highly optimized for joins and filtering. Do not reinvent the wheel using LINQ

Comment: Before answer, can you show Model classes with navigation properties?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Join in EF is not very correct to use when there are navigation properties. I also added a model of the main table (other entities are similar).

Comment: @Jr.MediocreCoder Unfortunately, the requirement is to use EF.

Comment: @egeo EF is an ORM, not embedded SQL or a SQL replacement. That means Object to Relational Mapper. It's meant to give the impression of working with in-memory Objects instead of Relational constructs. You *can* map entities to reporting view and actually you should. This will allow you to create, optimize and *fix* complex queries without having to redeploy your application.

Comment: @egeo in your example, what are the *objects*? They aren't Student and Amount. The query itself needs some fixing and is probably better as a materialized view, or a precalculated reporting table. You can't create either through EF. You can map to them though

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the following EF Core query:

```cs
var query = from student in db.Student
    join region in db.Region on student.RegionId equals region.id
    join district in db.District on student.DistrictId equals district.id
    join department in db.Department on student.DepartmentId equals department.id
    join amount in db.Amount on student.Id equals amount.student_id 
    where amount.Year == 2020
    group amount by new
    {
        student.RegionId,
        RegionName = region.Name,
        student.DistrictId,
        DistrictName = district.Name,
        student.DepartmentId,
        DepartmentName = department.Name
    } into g
    select new
    {
        g.Key.RegionName,
        g.Key.DistrictName,
        g.Key.DepartmentName,
        Cnt = g.Count(),
        Value = g.Sum(a => a.Value)
    };
var result = await query.ToListAsync();
```

It is translated into the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT r.name AS "RegionName", d.name AS "DistrictName", d0.name AS "DepartmentName",
    count(*)::int AS "Cnt", COALESCE(sum(a.value), 0.0) AS "Value"
FROM student AS s
INNER JOIN region AS r ON s.region_id = r.id
INNER JOIN district AS d ON s.district_id = d.id
INNER JOIN department AS d0 ON s.department_id = d0.id
INNER JOIN amount AS a ON s.id = a.student_id
WHERE a.year = 2020
GROUP BY s.region_id, r.name, s.district_id, d.name, s.department_id, d0.name
```

If you need `LEFT JOIN` then it will be:

```cs
var query = from student in db.Student
    join region in db.Region on student.RegionId equals region.id into rg
    from r in rg.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join district in db.District on student.DistrictId equals district.id into dg
    from d in dg.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join department in db.Department on student.DepartmentId equals department.id into dpg
    from dp in dpg.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join amount in db.Amount on student.Id equals amount.student_id
    where amount.Year == 2020
    group amount by new
    {
        student.RegionId,
        RegionName = r.Name,
        student.DistrictId,
        DistrictName = d.Name,
        student.DepartmentId,
        DepartmentName = dp.Name
    } into g
    select new
    {
        g.Key.RegionName,
        g.Key.DistrictName,
        g.Key.DepartmentName,
        Cnt = g.Count(),
        Value = g.Sum(a => a.Value)
    };
```

Comment: @egeo, I've updated the answer with the EF Core query.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query:

```cs
var query = 
    from s in db.Student
    from a in s.Amounts
    where a.Year == 2020
    group a by new 
    { 
        s.RegionId, 
        RegionName = s.Region.Name, 
        s.DistrictId, 
        DistrictName = s.District.Name, 
        s.DepartmentId, 
        DepartmentName = s.Department.Name 
    } into g
    select new 
    {
        x.Key.RegionId,
        x.Key.DepartmentName,
        x.Key.DistrictId,            
        x.Key.DistrictName,            
        x.Key.DepartmentId,
        x.Key.DepartmentName,
        Cnt = x.Select(v => v.StudentId).Distinct().Count(),
        Value = x.Sum(v => v.Value)
    };

var result = await query.ToListAsync();
```

Not sure that `Cnt = x.Select(v => v.StudentId).Distinct().Count()` will be translated, it depends on EF Core version.

**UPDATE** - added equivalent to the SQL query:

```cs
var groupingQuery = 
    from s in db.Student
    from a in s.Amounts
    where a.Year == 2020
    group a by new 
    { 
        s.RegionId, 
        s.DistrictId, 
        s.DepartmentId, 
    } into g
    select new 
    {
        x.Key.RegionId,
        x.Key.DistrictId,            
        x.Key.DepartmentId,
        Cnt = x.Select(v => v.StudentId).Distinct().Count(),
        Value = x.Sum(v => v.Value)
    };

var query = 
    from g in groupingQuery
    join region in db.Region on g.RegionId equals region.id
    join district in db.District on g.DistrictId equals district.id
    join department in db.Department on g.DepartmentId equals department.id
    select new
    {
        g.RegionId,
        RegionName = region.Name,
        g.DistrictId,
        DistrictName = district.Name,
        g.DepartmentId,
        DepartmentName = department.Name,
        g.Cnt,
        g.Value
    };

var result = await query.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: It turns out that the main idea is to include names in the grouping key as well? Yes, it works, but at the SQL query level (without EF) I wouldn't do that, what do you say?

Comment: Better to compare execution plan. I can mimic your query also, but do we need that?

Comment: Added variant which should should generate almost the same SQL.